# Did Russia's parliament, Duma, propose invading Poland in 2022?

Tags: politics, war, russia, poland, russo-ukrainian-war

Twitter user @sentdefender, with >160K followers, [recently tweeted](https://twitter.com/sentdefender/status/1525176043539144704)

> The Russian State Duma has proposed that after the Invasion of Ukraine, that Poland be Invaded and denazified next due to their clear Support for "Nazi Elements" in Ukraine and around the World while also providing Aid to Ukraine that results in the death of Russian Troops.

I cannot find confirmation of this on Duma's website.

Did Russian [Duma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Duma) propose invading Poland?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine is that an answer? If so, please post it as one (and, perhaps, de-americanise it for the rest of the world!). If not, it shouldn't exist at all - comments are for seeking clarification not pseudo-answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that some members have proposed that though it is unclear if it has the support of the entire body or not.

https://www.express.co.uk/news/world/1610029/Putin-Poland-denazification-Ukraine-war-NATO-latest-Russia-state-duma-update

> Russia's State Duma deputy proposed to put "Poland next in line for denazification after Ukraine" with a post on his Telegram account. Oleg Morozov is a member of the Kremlin's party United Russia's Superior Council and Duma deputy. It comes as the Russian authorities blocked the accounts of the Polish embassy in Moscow on Friday.

> The high-level Russian official wrote that a potential military operation against Poland would be a response to Warsaw's statement that Russia is a "cancerous tumour".

Comment: Even the claim that "some members" (plural) have proposed it isn't fully supported by your sources here; all you've got is a quote from *one* guy.

Comment: @MarkAmery I am confused what the issue with that statement is?

Comment: I don't think it is much of a stretch from the second in command saying something to saying that he is not the only one saying it.

Comment: Well, it seems like a stretch to me. It's certainly *possible* that other members have proposed the same thing, but absent any concrete evidence of that, it seems unlikely to me. Invading Poland is a pretty nutty thing to propose, and by default I'd assume that only this one loon has proposed it.

Comment: @MarkAmery : or they might deliberately propose it to elicit a reaction or to manipulate others, without actually carrying it out. "proposing" is not the same thing as "deciding to do it".

Comment: @MarkAmery Isn't most of what Russia has been doing recently pretty nutty? One of the reasons they claim to be doing it is because of NATO getting close but hasn't that also caused other countries to change their stance on joining NATO? Previously neutral countries are now considering asking to join NATO and various threats have been made about that. Honestly a lot of what is happening doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: I would argue that "some guy said something online" and "it is the official policy of this government body" are two very different things, even if said "some guy" is a member of said government body. To me, "the Duma proposed" would *at the very least* imply that some form of statement to that effect was formally introduced and debated. I'm not even going to require that it was voted on, let alone passed. Just introduced into the official record.

Comment: @JörgWMittag And you are correct, I am not suggesting that it is the official policy rather that it has been brought up which is what I have stated in my answer.  If it becomes an official stand or something that a few bring up remains to be seen.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yeah, the US equivalent would be taking whatever's the latest nonsense that Marjorie Taylor Greene has proposed on social media and saying that Congress proposed it.

Comment: @Eugene I don't know that is how I would compare it as the person I am referring to is in a high position of leadership and not just a random memeber

Answer (score 6):

Oleg Morozov, a deputy of Duma, stated the following [in his social media](https://telemetr.me/content/olegmorozov0511/post/585/):

> Своими заявлениями о России, как "раковой опухоли", и о "контрибуции",
> которую мы должны выплатить Украине, Польша побуждает нас поставить ее
> на первое место в очередь на денацификацию после Украины.

Translation:

> With their statements about Russia being a "cancerous tumor" and an
> "indemnity" we owe to Ukraine, Poland urges us put them first in line
> for denazification after Ukraine.

Multiple [media](https://news.yahoo.com/russian-lawmaker-warns-poland-next-183320526.html) [outlets](https://www.express.co.uk/news/world/1610029/Putin-Poland-denazification-Ukraine-war-NATO-latest-Russia-state-duma-update) name Morozov specifically as the source of the quote, so it is reasonable to assume that post is the original source of the claim.

One can infer from this statement that it proposes an invasion, but it was not stated in parliamentary discussions, but rather as a personal opinion.

Several other deputies of Duma also expressed outrage at the words of Polish Premier that prompted the post in question, but as far as I'm aware, no official deliberations were conducted by Duma on this matter at this time.

Thus, the answer to your question would be no, Russian Duma did not propose invading Poland.

Answer (score 3):

A number of users under the tweet point to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/rianru/status/1525139085777588227) by RIA - [a russian state-owned news agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIA_Novosti) - as the original source for the claim that "the state duma" proposed this.

It states:

> В Госдуме предложили поставить Польшу в очередь на денацификацию

Twitter translates this to:

> The State Duma proposed to put Poland in line for denazification

The [RIA article](https://ria.ru/20220513/polsha-1788409643.html) is available online. I don't speak Russian, but using google translate, it can be confirmed that the story is 1) talking about the "state duma" in the headline, but 2) actually about a Telegram post by Morozov as described in the other answers.

Comment: No, it translates to "In the State Duma, it was proposed..." There is a subtle difference here.